# Is it possible to get the list of all instances in a DigitalOcean App(PaaS)

Tags: digital-ocean

As I know, I can use api
https://developers.digitalocean.com/documentation/v2/#update-an-app

to scale up/down an app dynamically.

I hope to get the IP address of all instances.

But I can not find any API that can get the list of all instances in a DigitalOcean App.

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this information is inaccessible.

DigitalOcean Apps is a platform atop Kubernetes (Knative?) and the IPs of the containers that are your apps' workers aren't exposed (and are probably non-routable).

The load-balancer is possibly all you can get.